# How to pass data while using get method in xdr

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

As IE does not support cross domain issues, we have to use get or post method by using xdr, my problem is, I don't know how to pass data while using get method with xdr.

Code snippet for get method using jquery ajax is like -

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    url: site_url,
    data: params,
    success: onsuccess,
    error:onError
});
```

but suppose if I write this code for xdr it will be like -

```
var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
xdr.CacheControl = "no-cache";
xdr.open("get", site_url);
xdr.onload = function () { 
                   var data = $.parseJSON(xdr.responseText);
                   onsuccess(data);
             }
xdr.onerror = function() {alert('err');};
xdr.send();
```

Now in this, I do not know where to pass data!!!

Please help me out to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It all happens in the ".open" method.

Lets say you want to pass some JSON or an object to the request.

Do it like so...

```
var my_request_data = {
   "whatever" : "whatever",
   "again"    : "whatever again",
   "you get"  : "the point..."
};

my_request_data = $.param(my_request_data);

xdr.open("get", "http://url.com/to/get/or/post/too/" + my_request_data);
```

jQuery turns the JSON object into URL friendly params and then it is sent to the server.

That is how you pass data!